# atomicity and consistency across services in SOA

Tags: java, rest, transactions, soa, xa

I am facing some issues w.r.t. **atomicity and durability** across services in my ecosystem.

Suppose I have services A, B and C. Now a client talks to service A to do something. But service A in turn talks to B and c then forwards results to client. Suppose i am able to update some resources as part of service B but fails to update some resources as part of C service. Than how will i achieve consistency across services i.e. if C fails than all updates as part of service B should also get rolled back.

Is XA is the way to go or something else more elegant is present.

Comment: According to ["SOA Patterns"](http://books.google.com.uy/books/about/SOA_Patterns.html?id=n3-5PgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) book author, to use distributed transactions is considered an antippatern (Transactional Integration), a more suitable approach to SOA practices  is to implement what it's called Saga Pattern. May be you can find some chapter of this book usefull.

Comment: @GabrielAramburu could you please explain a bit here, so that it will be helpful for the people who does not have the book. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is XA is the way to go or something else more elegant is present.

One of SOA aim is to achieve loose coupling. 
There are several forms of loose coupling (or different System's aspects where loose coupling can be applied).
One of these loose coupling forms is related to Transactions.

With XA transaction, you have the advantage that your code doesn't need deal with alternative flows, thus, the code is clearer and easier to maintain.

At this point, you have an `elegant` solution for your problem.

However, this "simplicity" has a cost: your services are coupled in a Transactional form. 
Specially, if some service participating in your transaction belongs to a third-party system (it is not under your control), there is a risk that external systems lock on your service.

If this kind of coupling become a problem, the solution could be to eliminate XA transactions and  write code that deal with the alternative flows. Here is where the Saga pattern appears. The idea is that if one step of your business process fails, programmatically you will have to maintain consistency implementing what it is called Compensation code.

At this point, you also have an `elegant` solution for your problem, although your code became more complex.

I have seen scenarios like the one you have described, where the services code are needlessly too complex due to the absence of XA transactions.
I say needlessly because the transactional coupling there wasn't a problem.
I think it's much difficult to see a case where transactional coupling is big enough that to replace XA transactions with Compensation code worth the effort.